# How to chain explode and struct field selection?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql, explode

The dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([([(1, 2), (3, 4)],)], 'col_name array<struct<c1:int,c2:int>>')

df.show()
# +----------------+
# |        col_name|
# +----------------+
# |[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]|
# +----------------+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- col_name: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- c2: integer (nullable = true)
```

I `explode` the array (the result is a column of type `struct<c1:int,c2:int>`).
And then select every struct field *(but I `select` twice)*:

```py
df = df.select(
    F.explode('col_name')
).select(
    [f'col.{c}' for c in ('c1', 'c2')]
)
```

```py
df.show()
# +---+---+
# | c1| c2|
# +---+---+
# |  1|  2|
# |  3|  4|
# +---+---+

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- c1: integer (nullable = true)
#  |-- c2: integer (nullable = true)
```

I know I can shorten the second select to just `'col.*'`. But I would still have 2 selects.

**Question.** Is there a method to select struct fields *right after the explode* with only 1 select?

As the result of the explode has schema `struct<c1:int,c2:int>`, I thought this would work...

```py
df = df.select(
    [F.explode('col_name')[c] for c in ('c1', 'c2')]
)
```

> AnalysisException: No such struct field c1 in col

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the magic inline

```
df.selectExpr('inline(col_name)').show()

+---+---+
| c1| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  3|  4|
+---+---+
```

Comment: Truly, looks like magic!

Comment: Accept it,it's magic

Comment: Sure, just ran a couple of tests ;)